# Django rest framework: mixing some fields of one model with another and make a serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the `User` model and `UserProfile` model.

```
User model contains the following:

email
password

first_name
last_name
```

and

```
UserProfile model contains

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    photo = models.ImageField()
    location = models.TextField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I want to create an api endpoint where User can edit the following fields and save after login

```
--> from User
first_name
last_name

--> from Userprofile
photo
location
phone
```

In normal Django forms. I can use multiple forms and validate them and save. User will see them as one form.

Eg:

```
if request.POST():
    formA = UserForm(instance=request.user)
    formB = UserProfileForm(instance=request.user.userprofile_set)
    a_valid = formA.is_valid()
    b_valid = formB.is_valid()
    # we do this since 'and' short circuits and we want to check to whole page for form errors
    if a_valid and b_valid:
        a = formA.save()
        b = formB.save()
```

In serializers how can I do this

Comment: [This](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) might give you an idea on how to approach this

Comment: I am asking. How to achieve this. I have tried with forms I have posted some sample idea with forms

Comment: @dbdb I have gone through that, then i my POST JSON string should have seperate keys for each model. EG: `{ "user": {"first_name": ,"last_name": }, "userprofile": {...all its fields here}`. then its possible. OR `{ "first_name": ,"last_name": , "userprofile": {...all its fields here}`

Comment: It's more of `{"first_name": "", "last_name": "", "userprofile": {"photo": ""}}`. If you nest the `userprofile`, it should be possible to use just one serializer

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

> UserSerializer

```
class UserSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    def update(instance, validated_data):
        instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name', instance.first_name)
        instance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', instance.last_name)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

> UserProfileSerializer

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfileSerializer
        fields = ['photo', 'location', 'phone']

    def update(instance, validated_data):
        instance.photo = validated_data.get('photo', instance.photo)
        instance.location = validated_data.get('location', instance.location)
        instance.phone = validated_data.get('phone', instance.phone)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Then create a view like this which receives data in this format:

```
{
    user: {first_name: "", last_name: ""},
    profile:{photo: "", location: "", phone: ""}
}
```

> The view

```
class UserDetailUpdateView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, username):
        user_data = request.data['user']
        profile_data = request.data['profile']

        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
        serialized_user = UserSerializer(user, data=user_data, partial=True)
        serialized_profile = UserProfileSerializer(user.userprofile, data=profile_data, partial=True)

        if serialized_user.is_valid() and serialized_profile.is_valid():
            serialized_user.save()
            serialized_profile.save()
            return Response('Updated', status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response('Error occurred', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```